# How to continuously check time in jQuery from a fixed time

Tags: jquery, timer

I have a very simple problem in which I need to do something after 30 minute from a fixed time and then do something else after 30 minute 15 seconds from the same fixed time. I am using the following code to achieve that but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/date.js" />"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/wikedlynotsmart/creationTime",
        success: function (data) {
            var date = parseFloat(data.creationDate);
            var timeCreation = new Date(date);
            var timeAlert = new Date(timeCreation);
            timeAlert.setMinutes(timeCreation.getMinutes() + 30);
            var timeAutoSubmit = new Date(timeCreation);
            timeAutoSubmit.setMinutes(timeCreation.getMinutes() + 30);
            timeAutoSubmit.setSeconds(timeCreation.getSeconds() + 15);
            setInterval(function () {
                if (new Date() == timeAlert) {
                    alert("time is over");
                }
                if (new Date() == timeAutoSubmit) {
                    $('form').submit();
                }
            }, 1000);
        },
        async: false,
        dataType: "json"
    });
});
</script>
```

Could someone help me understand am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: "Time's up! has been edited to "time is over" but still it does not work.

Comment: what about this doesnt work?  Also, you forgot to add the end quote to "Time's up!".

Comment: what format will `data.creationDate` be in when it's returned from the AJAX call?

Comment: Have you checked 'date' to make sure it's what you expect it to be?

Comment: @Alnitak: Yes, its the json format returned from an MVC controller. Yes, its the asynchronous ajax call.

Comment: @Grim: Yes, I've checked the date, timeCreation, timeAlert and timeValue as well and they all show their values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't count once a second, if you can avoid it.  AFAIK you also can't compare `Date()` objects like that.

Work out the initial delay between 30 minutes after the returned time and now, and wait that long.  Then wait another 15 seconds.

```
var create = new Date(data.creationDate).getTime() + (30 * 60 * 1000);
var now = new Date().getTime();

var delay = Math.max(0, create - now);  // initial delay
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Time's up!");  // not alert() - that blocks the UI
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('form').submit();
    }, 15000);
}, delay);
```

Answer (score 0):

Will

```
setTimeout('myFunction();',1800000);
```

not work?

(1,800,000 is 30 minutes in milliseconds).

Comment: What if someone reloads the page? Would the time not start timing again for 1800000 from 0? I need to do those two tasks from a fixed time for which a synchronous ajax request is being sent to my MVC controller which is getting that fixed time. I first actually did it that way only but realized that reloading the page was creating the issue :)

Comment: Don't pass strings to `setTimeout`.

Comment: @skip - if you need timer to continue when someone loads the page, you'll have to use cookies or a database (or some other persistant method)

Comment: @FelixKling - quite right, but I was trying to make life simple. I suspected there was some issue with using setTimeout anyway.

Comment: @Grim & FelixKling: The json data that I am getting back is from database itself. So I tried to add 30 min and 30 min, 15 seconds to that tiime and do the comparision and get the thing done. But it doesn't work. I am using "time is over" for "Time's up!" to avoid the double quote issue but still no help.

Comment: @skip 1.  you're trying to compare date objects, which AFAIK you can't do.  2.  those date objects have 1ms resolution, but you're only checking roughly every 1000 ms.  The chances of your test hitting the precise millisecond when that time has elapsed are pretty negligible.

Comment: @Alnitak: I totally agree with you and I think that's where the code is failing but I don't really know how to fix that. I barely know javascript. But I will try to do just what you've suggested. The comparision result always seem to come `false`.